# How to find and edit a single field with MongoDB collections

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, express, put

I have a database with MongoDB that's storing my notes and users.

I want a function that will send a put request using "userId" and "note". Then analyze whether or not the noteID exists for that particular user. If it does, then modify. If it doesn't, then add.

Before:

```
 [
 {
   "_id": "abc"
   "userId" : "123",
   "notes" : [
      {"note": {"noteID":[0,0], "text":"old1"}},
      {"note": {"noteID":[0,1], "text":"old2"}},
   ]
 }

 },
 {
   "_id": "xyz"
   "userId" : "999",
   "notes" : [
   ]
 }
 ]
```

Call this function

```
this.userId = 123
this.note = {"noteID":[0,0], "text":"new1"}
someFunction(userId, note) //this one modifies

this.userId = 999
this.note = {"noteID":[0,0], "text":"new1"}
someFunction(userId, note) //this one creates
```

After:

```
 [
 {
   "_id": "abc"
   "userId" : "123",
   "notes" : [
      {"note": {"noteID":[0,0], "text":"new1"}},
      {"note": {"noteID":[0,1], "text":"hello 123"}},
   ]
 }

 },
 {
   "_id": "xyz"
   "userId" : "999",
   "notes" : [
      {"note": {"noteID":[0,0], "text":"new1"}},
   ]
 }
 ]
```

what is inside of `someFunction() {}?`

Comment: That doesn't look like JavaScript - you usually don't assign variables inside parameters, and it looks invalid.

Comment: Yes that's true. I've edited the question to make it easier to read.